# How can I use the JavaScript InfoVis Toolkit in the .net project

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-2, infovis

Now I'm doing some work about Code Coverage and Treemap.
And my projects are c# projects such as Asp.net MVC.

I want to use "JavaScript InfoVis Toolkit", because it's effect is very good and it supports interactive animations.
But I could not find some other materials besides the demo and i don't know if it can be used in the .net project.

Is there anybody know how to use it in .net project?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using this now in a asp mvc 2 project - it works, you just need to be careful with the json data you pass for the visualizations (serializing attributes  like "$color").
Add references in the view to the library and other js code you use to set up the visualization or do that by using some resources loader.